# Which words belong to "that" in this context?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-structure

> Chapter 5 describes this historical process in which the referendum
> **became** an institutional constraint that **induced** cooperation among all
> major political parties and **led to** negotiated legislation and mutual
> adjustment among interest groups.
>
> *- Swiss Democracy by Wolf Linder*

There is a thing that is ambiguous to me. In the first glance I think the word **induced** and **led to** belongs to **that**. But in another reading of this sentence **led to** and **became** can belong to referendum as "in which referendum became ... and led to ...".

I want to know which one is true. Because in the first varian referendum is a **constraint** which led to negotiated legislation. I'm not sure how can a **constraint** lead to this.

Comment: I don't see any ambiguity. _That_ refers to _the referendum_, so your 'other reading' doesn't mean anything different.

Answer (score 1):

**that** is a relative pronoun: it connects together two clauses, and represents a noun in the main clause buy acting as the subject of object pronoun in the subordinate clause.

In this particular sentence, the subordinate clause comes in two parts, linked by **and**, and **that** represents **referendum** (which is also an **institutional constraint**) as the subject of the two parts of the subordinate clause.

> main clause: Chapter 5 describes this historical process in which the referendum became an institutional constraint
> subordinate clause pt1: that induced cooperation among all major political parties
> subordinate clause pt2: that led to negotiated legislation and mutual adjustment among interest groups.

Answer (score 0):

It is the **constraint** that **induced cooperation** and **led to negotiation and adjustment**. It may not make a big difference, since the referendum became the constraint, but I think **that** links syntactically to the nearest preceding noun.